# Member function wrapper in base class

Tags: c++

I'm trying to build an abstract class which provides a function that runs any passed member function inside a std::future but I have no clue how to write the function signature. It must accept any member class of the base and subclasses. I have following:

```
template<typename T>
class Dao {
    public:
    virtual T Create(T obj) = 0;
    virtual T Upsert(T obj) = 0;
    virtual void Delete(int id) = 0;
    virtual T Get(int id) = 0;

    // This function is supposed to run any member function passed to it
    // inside the future. The passed function can be either from the Dao 
    // class or one of its derived classes.
    template <typename U, typename... Args>
    std::future<U> RunAsync(U (Dao::*func)(Args...), Args... args){
      return std::async(std::launch::async,func,this,args...);
    }
};
class ModelDao : public Dao<Model> {
   public:
   // implementing the virtual functions
   MyModel Foo(){ ... };
};
class Model { ... };
```

The only way I can use it is with the functions declared in the Dao class:

```
std::future<Model> f = dao.RunAsync(&Dao<Model>::Get, 100);
```

Anything else is throwing something like this:

```
template argument deduction/substitution failed:
mismatched types 'Dao<Model>' and 'ModelDao' 
'Foo' is not a member of 'Dao<Model>'
```

But I'd like to use them like this (either f1 or f3 is fine if both isn't possible):

```
ModelDao mDao; 
Model mModel;
std::future<Model> f1 = mDao.RunAsync(&Dao::Create,mModel);
std::future<void> f2 = mDao.RunAsync(&ModelDao::Foo);
std::future<Model> f3 = mDao.RunAsync(&ModelDao::Create,mModel);
```

I know I could just use the Dao like this

```
ModelDao mDao;
std::future<Model> f = std::async(std::launch::async, &ModelDao::Get,&mDao,100);
std::future2<void> f2 = std::async(std::launch::async [&](){mDao.Foo();});
```

but I find the first approach easier to type out and probably easier to maintain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
template <typename U, typename Q, typename... Args>
std::future<U> RunAsync(U (Q::*func)(Args...), Args... args){
  return std::async(std::launch::async, func, static_cast<Q*>(this), args...);
}
```

Note: i didn't add checks for `Q` type being descendant from `Dao<T>`. If you use virtual inheritance, then `static_cast` might not be enough and you might be forced to use `dynamic_cast` instead.